# Need a proper example for custom expendable list view with JSON array

Tags: android, json, android-studio

I searched almost every tutorials and never fiend a perfect example for a custom expendable listview, where parent node and child node data will fetch from web server using JSON array. Please help me anyone, atleast give me any proper tutorial link so that I can understand the whole process.

Answer (score 0):

Download the zip from this link:
https://github.com/alessandroargentieri/AndroidToWebService

Inside there is an Android Application which asks for a JSON message from a PHP Web service which takes the data from a Database MySQL.

If you want to see the PHP page, it is at the end of MainActivity.java as a commented code.

Comment: Ya, I know this thing, actually what I want, suppose I have an Expendable Listview, where parent node display data from server, using the same process as your example, and then when I click on particular parent node it will display there co-responding child node